# Need to color the header in excel from SSIS package

Tags: excel, vb.net, ssis-2012

Requirement: I need to export data from a query to formatted excel sheet using SSIS. Currently working with .xls

What I tried: I used an excel sheet with pre-formatted header row (first row) as template and I copy and rename to a new file to export data. When I run the package, all data rows will have the same formatting as the header. I tried googling only to find many people having the same issue.

Now I am writing to a non-header formatted excel sheet and using a script task, I am trying to format the headers alone. Below is the code

```
Dim appexcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        Dim newbook As Workbook
        Dim sheet As Object

        Dim Connection As String = "..My path\\All_Current.xls" '
        newbook = appexcel.Workbooks.Open(Connection)
        sheet = newbook.Worksheets("REPORT")
        Dim selectedSheet As Worksheet = DirectCast(sheet, Worksheet)
        'Dim style As Style = selectedSheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("ColorStyle")
        
        selectedSheet.Cells.Range("A1", "I1").Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue
        'selectedSheet.Cells.Range("A1", "I1").Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White
        'selectedSheet.Cells.Range("A1", "I1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        'selectedSheet.Cells.Range("A1", "I1").Font.Name = "Verdana"
        'selectedSheet.Cells.Range("A1", "I1").Font.Size = 10

        newbook.Save() ' This line the compiler runs forever
        newbook.Close(False)
        appexcel.Quit()
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

I am unable to check if my code is working or not. If I debug, it keeps running at the '.save()' line. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with the below code

```
'newbook.Save()
appexcel.ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False ' to prevent compatibility check dialog showing
appexcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save() ' saves only this workbook
newbook.Close(False)
appexcel.Quit()
```